# Soap/php/lighttpd server errors, can not find file that is there?

Tags: php, soap

I'm sticking a web interface which I've been given (that works on other systems) onto a switch, which happens to be in php/soap.

I get this error

```
Warning: require(/class_main.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /jffs2/usbflash0/ran/www/includes/config.php on line 4

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/class_main.php' (include_path='.:') in /jffs2/usbflash0/ran/www/includes/config.php on line 4
```

config.php:

```
<?php^M
        require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/errors.php');^M
        require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/library.php');^M
        require(get_structures_directory().'/class_main.php');  ^M
        error_log(get_structures_directory());
        require(get_structures_directory().'/class_softcore.php');^M
        require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/format.php');^M
?>^M
```

Which looks for class_main.php in here:

```
1.0.1/  1.0.3/  2.0.5/  2.0.7/  3.0.10/ 3.0.12/ 3.0.3/  3.0.5/  3.0.7/  3.0.9/
1.0.2/  1.0.4/  2.0.6/  3.0.1/  3.0.11/ 3.0.2/  3.0.4/  3.0.6/  3.0.8/
```

Now `class_main.php` is in some of these version folders and not in some of them. What is the issue here? is it trying to use one of the folders where it is not located?

Comment: The code from config.php has the error, but the reason is within the `get_structures_directory()` function, which returns an empty string. Find out why.

Answer (score 1):

Well First class_main.php must be in all the folders, So application will not fail for any instance. If it is unlikely you can check for version and require only in that cases like

```
switch($version)
{
    case "1":
    case "2":
         require($file_path);
         break;

}
```

You can also use include instead of require which will give you warnings instead of error, However it is unadvisable specially on pure php libraries, As it will gave application undefined behaviour.